# redirect URLs to lowercase in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

For some reason URLs in Firebase hosting are case sensitive and thus redirects don't work when one of the characters is uppercase. This is very common in users using tablets which autocapitalise text.

Is there a way to change this behaviour in the `firebase.json` file to make URLs case insensitive or to automatically convert URLs to lowercase?

Answer (score -1):

This is accomplished by adding a "redirects" entry in your firebase.json

from firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [],
"redirects": [{
  "source" : "/TARGET_SITE_FOLDER",
  "destination" : "/target_site_folder",
  "type" : 301
  }]
}
```

Solved it for me!

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hi Joao, this doesn't really answer the question though. What if the user writes a URL as `Target_site_folder` or `Target_Site_Folder`?

Comment: I wanted to redirect multiple URLs on my Gatsby website and adding redirects is not a possible solution as it has hundreds of URLs. Does anyone have a solution to make this work with dynamic configuration?